# House hunting with kanban tools

Tags: project-management, kanban

I want to search for a new place, but as you know, this is no easy task. You have to apply to lots of landlords and keep track of data and add comments of these places. Furthermore, you have each "Place" in a different "State": "To consider" -> "Applied" -> "Negotiating" (and "rejected by me", "rejected by landlord", etc). Also, I'm not the only one looking, this will be a collaborative task...

I feel like this could be easily managed with a Kanban, each card having some data fields like "price", "sq. meters", "price per sq. meters", "utilities included", "LOCATION (coords)", "time to work", etc.

Is there any highly configurable/adaptable and preferably self-hosted platform for this? I wouldn't mind having to create a plugin for some things if I could.

It has to:

- Be collaborative
- Let you create custom states (columns)
- Let you add custom fields to the "template card". One of them geolocated, and one of them a "header picture".
- OPTIONAL: Auto calculate some fields (like €/m²)
- OPTIONAL: Plugin system
- KILLER FEATURE: Geolocation support. Open a map and show the cards, being able to filter by fields values.

PD: About what Kanban software do I already know, I just used GitHub Project/Issues, and Quire.io

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Kanban is not the right approach for this, IMHO. With Kanban you would try to pull tasks to their final states - which is likely not what is best to find a house.

Comment: After a few months, I think the best approach would be to use a knowledge management tool like Logseq or Obsidian, and provide a Kanban view for tasks (contact owner, visit at an specified time), as well as a Map / Whiteboard view of the data.